# Jquery's Multiple Selector not working in IE

Tags: jquery

I Have developed this code for making same height of the divs as same as a specific div but its not working in IE9 and below. I dont know the mistake i am doing...

The demo:-
http://jsfiddle.net/ZWkm5/

JS:-

```
$(window).load(function() {

    var getWrapHeight = $('#wrap').height();
    console.log(getWrapHeight);
    $(".a1, .a2, .a3, .a4").css({
        "height" : getWrapHeight,
    });

});
```

Comment: Can't test that, so I won't go to the actual problem solving. One thing though... You are using classes for these 4 elements, why not use same class `$(".a")`? or maybe wrap them with a parent and target them with something like: `$("#a > div")`

Answer (score 1):

`console.log` actually throws a JavaScript error in IE because it doesn't exist.

If you had turned on the setting "Display a notification about every script error" in IE, you'd get (this is what I got, I have it turned on):

> Error: 'console' is undefined.

Remove that and it works.

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/ZWkm5/1/**

**If you REALLY want to keep that log in there, you could replace it with:**

```
if (window.console){
    console.log(getWrapHeight);
}
```

Comment: Instead of removing, isn't `if(window.console){ console.log(getWrapHeight); }` better ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed Good shout, added :)

Comment: or perhaps this: `window.console && console.log( getWrapHeight );` ..or http://jsfiddle.net/ZWkm5/2/ ( I think there might be a plugin that does something similar, actually... ).